# What's SQL Server version 8?

Tags: sql-server

So, my JDBC driver says this:

"SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver."

But what the heck is SQL Server version 8?  All I can find references to are year numbers, and the guys who set up the database aren't around for me to ask.  Any ideas?

Comment: [First Google hit for "sql server version numbers".](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) (And for "sql server version" but I tried that later and it might be Google's personalisation.)

Comment: What the heck?  I googled "sql server version 8" at the time and it was no help at all, but the results are great now.  Maybe I was drunk...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Version 8 is SQL Server 2000.

Some more information here (thanks, dcaswell):  [SQL Server file names vs versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753886/sql-server-file-names-vs-versions/18754188#18754188)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Version 8 is SQL Server 2000.

As SQL Server 2012 is 11,
SQL Server 2008 is 10 
And SQL Server 2005 is 9