# Change Tracking in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to enable [Change Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on a SQL Server Database that was installed via a third party application. Looking at the `Properties -> General -> Product` of the Server shows:

```
Product: Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition
Version: 9...
```

Judging from the [MS Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) and an [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322265/1972457) this is a SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3.

Is Change Tracking supported by SQL Server Express 2005?

Is there a **clean** way to track changes for a database in SQL Express 2005 if there is no Change Tracking?

On that server viewing Properties of a table does not show the Change Tracking option as it would in newer versions of a SQL database.

[image: Properties of a table in Sql Server (Change Tracking not showing)]

Answer (score 2):

> Is Change Tracking supported by SQL Server Express 2005?

No. It's a new feature introduced with SQL Server 2008.

> Is there a clean way to track changes for a database in SQL Express 2005 if there is no Change Tracking?

You can create a datetime column that defaults to the current time. This will tell what rows have been inserted since a time mark. For update, create a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189799(v=sql.90).aspx) to update that column to current time. For delete, use a trigger to insert the deleted row into a shadow table (something like `TableA_History`).