# VS2013 not picking up SQL2012 SSIS Custom Components

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am trying to create a custom SSIS component. While I use Visual Studio 2013 premium as my main IDE I seems to have fallen into the below problem.

When I create a SSIS custom component (class library, .Net 4.0 using dlls from 110's x86 folder) I am successfully able to compile, build, register at GAC and copy them to 110's DTS component folder. Now here is the problem. When I create Integration Services Project in VS2013, I cannot see my newly created component in the SSIS toolbox. While if I create ISP project in VS2010 I see my component.

Does anyone know what is going on? I created the component using VS2013, but VS2013 will not show my component in SSIS toolbox...

Bonus question - While playing around i deleted my AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SSIS\SSISToolboxConfig.dat file and now VS2013 shows exception in the ssis toolbox not showing any compoents. while vs2010 runs fine? The file is back now in the folder but problem persists. Exception says - exception while constructing the content of this frame.

Comment: What version of SSDT-BI is installed for VS 2012?

Comment: I am using 2013 and 2010 no 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wherever you've installed SQL Server, you'll have some number named folders

- 80 SQL Server 2000
- 90 SQL Server 2005
- 100 SQL Server 2008/SQL Server 2008 R2
- 110 SQL Server 2012
- 120 SQL Server 2014

[SQL Server file names vs versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753886/sql-server-file-names-vs-versions)

You're using Visual Studio to create an assembly. Period. Full stop. The version of studio you are using has no bearing on whether it's going to work with SSIS.

Instead, what *will* matter is the assemblies you reference. Unfortunately for those that develop custom tasks and components, they are bound to specific versions of the SQL Server product.

Since you're using the 110 assemblies, you're targeting SSIS for SQL Server 2012 which means SQL Server Data Tools - BI Edition/SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2010 *or* Visual Studio 2012.

Visual Studio 2013, once you install SSDT-BI addon will only target SQL Server 2014.

A wise man once commented

> I love the VS / SSDT / SQL Server version matrix. It's like a 47-sided Rubik's cube.

Comment: I added the files to the 120 DTS/PipelineComponent folder. Since my computer is 64 bit i pasted the files in both Program Files and Program Files (x86). Registry key refers to Program Files but there was no PipelineComponent Folder. I created and copied the files. Even then nothing in VS2013!
Which version of GACUTIL you think i should be using? I am using v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the fact that you need to right click on the components selection window (generally to the left) and pick the new custom component (assuming, you used the right GACUTIL version to deploy the component).

Comment: I am sorry, but i think this is not required. It is working now and i never had to do either the right click refresh or pickup the component.

Comment: Good for you. Care to share how you got around the issue?

Comment: I could not so choose to use vs 2010 for sql 2012.
If you download BI tools or SSDT they install SQL server 2014 on your machine. I decided to spend more time working on the actual work rather than figuring out this problem. For now i believe it is not possible. Which is also what briefly our DBAs said. I did not ask him for details.