# Do i need to install SSMS to create databases if i already have VS 2015 installed?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015, database-administration

I'm working in a project related to databases and I'm using a server with SQL server 2008 installed, but I'm working remotely from the office where I'm developing the software that will work with the database in VS 2015, which has built-in SQL tools to create databases, queries and so on, I have seen some tutorials where people have both VS and SSMS installed to work.

My questions are simple: is it really needed? whats the difference in creating the DB in VStudio vs SSMS?

Comment: No, it is not really needed. Of course SSMS is a tool more complete than the one integrated VS, but you can work with VS. On a personaI preference I always use SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can. See the following tutorial.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-create-database-project-in-visual-studio-2015/

To my knowledge there is no difference between using VS and SSMS, it is probably personal preference. For example, application developers who need to create a database probably prefer the familiarity of VS as well as keeping the DB file within their solution for code checking and what not. DB developers probably prefer SSMS because it is more intuitive and the UI is built around creating and managing databases.

I recommend using SSMS for creating databases.

**Update:** If you want to load data into SQL Server using Visual Studio, then you accomplish this with SQL Server **I**ntegration Services (SSIS). This is a big subject and I am not aware of how well versed you are in it, but to summarize, you will need the following:

1.) Install SQL Server Data Tools, which contains the Visual Studio templates for creating the following three project types: SS**I**S, SS**R**S, SS**A**S,

Where: **I** = Integration; **R** = Reporting; and **A** = Analysis

You can download SSDT for free at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

2.) Create an SSIS solution that loads your files. There are many steps to accomplish this, but a cursory check for SSIS file loaders online yielded the following:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/

One thing to note that is not contained in the above tutorial is that the versioning requirements of SSDT, VS, and SQL Server are nothing short of maddening. However, Microsoft seems to have tried to address this with VS2015 and up by allowing for SQL Server package targeting (I do not have VS2015 to confirm, I am using VS2017 and confirm that version). Once you create a solution, do the following:

1.) Right click on the project

2.) Click on Configuration Properties

3.) Set the TargetServerVersion to the version of SQL Server that you are running.

4.) Note: the components that are available in the toolbox will change - this is normal.

See the following SO post for this (read billinkc's answer): [VS2013 not picking up SQL2012 SSIS Custom Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754798/vs2013-not-picking-up-sql2012-ssis-custom-components)

Comment: I just discovered I cant import data from excel through visual studio, maybe that's a difference

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain loading data from an Excel file into SQL Server by using Visual Studio.