# SSIS Run through a batch file using DTExec.exe

Tags: batch-file, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS package that needs to run by a batch file. When I execute the SSIS package through SSDT it's working fine. But When I execute through "DTExec.exe" it's throwing below error message. I tried the deferent location of "
[image: DTExec.exe]" but I was failed. What could be the reason?

[image: My Batch File Command, Folder Structure, Log File, SSIS Package]

[image: In SSDT Package Runs Successfully]

[image: SSDT Version - 2017]

After switching to the 64bit dtexec located in the 140 directory, I have an error indicating it cannot create a task from XML for task "Script Task"

[image]

Targets SQL Server 2017

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dtexec you'll find under `IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\XXX\Binn\` where XXX is your version number is not for "regular" use. Those are for use with the Visual Studio/SSMS installation.

Instead, you're likely going to want one that is located in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
```

depending on your 32 vs 64 bit requirements as well as the version of SQL Server you have installed (and have targeted your packages)

Your screenshot shows 150 but I don't see a 150 version of the dtexec installed on your machine but that could just be my eyes

Comment: Sir. Tried on your recommendation. 
I'm getting below error message now (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe)
http://prntscr.com/sz332p

Comment: [140 is SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753886/sql-server-file-names-vs-versions) Is that the version you built your packages in? Right click on Project and under the Configuration menu, it ought to indicate what version it targets - typically the newest version so likely 2019

Comment: Yes sir. I have SQL Server 2017 and my SSDT Target version also Same.
http://prntscr.com/sz3h7f

But same error my batch file throwing

Comment: The "Cannot create a task from XML" is a different class of errors from your original "Could not create DTS.Application" At this point, I'd right click and disable the Script Task and try running the package to identify - is the package itself fundamentally broken or is there something specific to the Script Task causing the exception.

Comment: Sir, Here what I'm getting when I run the batch file while Script task disabled
http://prntscr.com/sz3rem

Comment: Sir, Could you help me