# dtexec error "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher."

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am having a really hard time with ssis lol.  I have visual studio 2019 community and I installed ssis & data tools following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15).  But when I try to run a package using dtexec, I get the error, To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.  But I thought that I did install ssis?  Also I am confused as to what which dtexec I should be using I have it in the 110,120, & 130 folders?

```
: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /f Package.dtsx
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 13.0.4561.14 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  6:31:15 PM
Error: 2021-01-27 18:31:15.76
   Code: 0xC000F427
   Source: Expression Task
   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.
End Error
Warning: 2021-01-27 18:31:15.76
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: Package
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  6:31:15 PM
Finished: 6:31:15 PM
Elapsed:  0.14 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message is correct stating that you need SSIS Server to run dtsx package.
Article you quoted describes how to install Development Environment for SSIS; this development environment allows to create and edit packages and run packages inside Visual Studio for debug purposes only. Package executions other than inside Visual Studio have to be done under SSIS Server environment.
Conclusion -- to run package in "productive environment" i.e. without manual actions in Visual Studio, you have to install some version of SSIS Server or execute package on existing SSIS server.

Different versions of DTExec in "110,120, & 130 folders" refer to different versions of SSIS. In the Visual Studio you have ability to develop packages for different versions of SSIS. As you specify SSIS version in SSIS Project properties, VS in package debug run corresponding version of DTExec. 130 corresponds to SQL Server 2016, see [SO answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754188/1010622) with more info.